# SQL Server 2005: Two or more string into one string and pass as parameter

Tags: string, sql-server-2005, sqlcommand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)

Hi All,

I am writing a SQL command for my project. I have to pass one string parameter to cursor.
But at that parameter I have to concatenate many strings, like this:

```
   DECLARE @strParam VARCHAR(MAX)
   SET @strParam = 'string1' + ',' + 'string2' + ',' ... etc
```

Then I want to use like this:

```
   SELECT * FROM tblResult WHERE Field1 IN (@strParam)
```

instead of the following statement:

```
   SELECT * FROM tblResult WHERE Field1 IN ('string1' + ',' + 'string2' + ',' ... etc)
```

So I need to get the format as like we set above.
How can I do that?

Best Regards,
Reds

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have already? Please clarify your question further.

Comment: What I want to do is I want to use @strParam in this statement :SELECT * FROM tblResult WHERE Field1 IN (@strParam) but If we run like that @strParam is not in this format ('string1','string2'), right? So the SELECT Statement will not get the require result.

Answer (score 0):

This will split the csv into a table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetIDs(
    @ids_csv        nvarchar(255))
    RETURNS @table_ids TABLE 
    (
        ID INT,
        PRIMARY KEY(ID)
    ) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @app_id varchar(10)
    DECLARE @pos int
    SET @ids_csv = LTRIM(RTRIM(@ids_csv))+ ','
    SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @ids_csv, 1)
    IF REPLACE(@ids_csv, ',', '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        WHILE @pos > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @app_id = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@ids_csv, @pos - 1)))
            INSERT INTO @table_ids(ID) VALUES(@app_id)
            SET @ids_csv = RIGHT(@ids_csv, LEN(@ids_csv) - @pos)
            SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @ids_csv, 1)
        END
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Then, you can do this:

```
 SELECT * FROM tblResult WHERE Field1 IN (SELECT * FROM GetIDs(@strParam))
```

Comment: I realised that the above splits integers, not strings.  Just note the difference.